# Is it possible to restrict an AWS IAM user from viewing CodeCommit repositories on the AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

I have the following AWS IAM policy for a user that has full read/write access to a single repo in AWS CodeCommit:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codecommit:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:123456789:Allowed-Repo"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to give this user AWS console access, but I only want the allowed repo to be viewable (all other repos should not be listed in the dashboard view). Is this possible? The only solution that I have seen so far involves adding the following to the policy:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "codecommit:ListRepositories",
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

This will show the user all repos in the codecommit dashboard. The user will not be able to read/write the repos, but they will still be able to view the repo names. Is it possible to restrict this?

Comment: "(all other repos should not be listed in the dashboard view)". That is not possible. You can't restrict what is displayed in lists like that in the web console. Either they have access to view the list or they don't. Amazon doesn't do any sort of filtering in resource lists in the web console based on permissions.

Comment: either you can grant ListRepositories, or not grant ListRepositories, but you can't list only one repository with ListRepositories.  I am not super familiar with code commit, but the user may not actually have to navigate through the listing page if they're provided a link to the individual repo page.

Comment: A slightly ugly option would be to disallow ListRepositories and force the user to know the name of the repo and its console URL, then the user can go directly to that URL and browse the allowed repo but cannot learn about any other repo.